# Viewing photos within an album in admin page

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to view all the photos in my album in the admin page.

I am new to Django so I am not sure how I can create a feature where all the photos would be displayed upon clicking on the album title. I believe that I would have to do something to the `AlbumAdmin` class but I am not sure what that would be. There is a one to many relationship between albums and pictures. I would simply like to grab all the pictures associated with that album when I click and enter the specific album page

[image]
[image]

Currently nothing is displayed when I click on the album. In my database there are in fact pictures in the album.

app/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from PIL import Image
from Boothie.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.conf import settings
import os.path
import re
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def images(self):
        lst = [x.photo for x in self.photo_set.all()]
        return lst

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        rgx = re.search(r'.*\w', self.title)
        self.title = rgx.group(0).replace(" ", "_")
        super(Album, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["title"]


def upload_path(self, filename):
        title = self.album.title
        if " " in title:
            title.replace(" ", "_")
        return os.path.join(title, filename)


class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def size(self):
        return "%s x %s" % (self.photo.width, self.photo.height)

    def thumbnail(self):
        thumbnail_html = "<a href=\"{0}{1}\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"{2}{3}\" height=\"80\" /></a>".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.photo.name, settings.MEDIA_URL, self.photo.name)
        return thumbnail_html

    thumbnail.allow_tags = True

    def photo_name(self):
        return os.path.basename(MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + self.photo.name)

    def photo_display(photo):
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (photo.photo.url, os.path.split(photo.photo.name)[1]))

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title", "photo"]
    list_display = ["photo_display", "thumbnail", "title", "album", "size"]
    list_filter = ["album"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is provided by [inline admin classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Photo

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["title"]
    model = Album
    inlines = [PhotoAdmin]
```

Note that these classes should be in your admin.py file, not models.py.